# C++ Inheritance with strings

Tags: c++, string, inheritance

So I found this problem on Inheritance I am try to figure out. this is what's required:

> Create a class called strMetric that will give information about a string. You should provide a default constructor and an overloaded constructor that takes a string as an argument.
>
> Your string metric class should have the following functioality
>
> A method called howLong that returns the length of the string
>
> A method called vowelCnt that returns the number of vowels in a string
>
> A method called charSum that returns the sum of all characters within the string
>
> A method called upperCase that returns the number of upper case characters
>
> A method called lowerCase that returns the number of lower case characters
>
> You are to use the strMetric class as the derived class and use the string class as the base class.
>
> NOTE:
>
> **Do not not create your own string class and derive from it.** You are to use the string class that is part of the std namespace and defined in

I have been working this out, and this is what I have, (right now I'm only working on 1 of the methods until I figure out how to do this properly)

//// strmetric.h ////

```
#ifndef STRMETRIC
#define STRMETRIC
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class strMetric : public string
{
private:

        public:
        strMetric();
        strMetric(string &s);
        int howLong(string s);
};
#endif
```

//// strmetric.cpp ////

```
#include "strmetric.h"

strMetric::strMetric()
    :string()
{
}
strMetric::strMetric(string &s)
    :string(s)
{
}

int strMetric::howLong(string s)
{ 
    return s.size();
}
```

/////main.cpp////

```
#include <iostream>
#include "strmetric.h"

strMetric testRun("Hello There");

int main()
{

cout << "Here is the sentence being tested " << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << testRun << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "String length " << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << testRun.length(testRun) << endl;
cout << endl;

}
```

So am I doing this correctly, or am I way off base? I'm having a hard time getting my head around this. If I'm doing it incorrectly could somebody show me how to do it correctly, I don't need the whole thing, just the one part I started so I can get a good idea on what I should be doing, thanks!

Comment: Basic rule: never inherit from `std` classes. Wrap them instead.

Comment: Wow, they're actually telling you to inherit from `std::string`?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  This isn't code review, if you're not getting your expected output then please let us know where and what you are seeing.  And yeah, never inherit from `std::string`.  I know that's a requirement, just know that is a horrible idea.

Comment: I think you could have `string` as your member variable.  It's not a good idea to inherit from it.

Comment: @JBentley: Not true (unfortunately): *"You are to use the strMetric class as the derived class and use the string class as the base class."* - and then: *"Do not not create your own string class and derive from it. You are to use the string class that is part of the std namespace and defined in"*.  What a dumb assignment.

Comment: @EdS. Ah yes, I didn't read it properly. Deleted.

Comment: What does it mean to wrap them? I've seen online where people say not to inherit from the std string class, but this thing calls for it. Maybe it's just some outdated thing I found online.

Comment: @MichellePeoples: Look up "Composition".  You would have a private `std::string` member and *use it* to do what you need, but you would not *inherit from it*.  Your class is *not* a string, therefore should *not* inherit from it. However, this is all irrelevant in terms of your assignment as you have to do so.  You can just politely tell your teacher that all of SO thinks s/he should re-evaluate the assignment as it is teaching you bad, bad things.

Comment: Instead of public inheritance, you could do private inheritance.

Comment: Find another problem. Whoever wrote this has a large knowledge gap.

Comment: @Yuushi: If only one could pick and chose the assignments they want to complete.

Comment: @EdS. Well, the wording suggests it's not actually assigned by a teacher: "I found this problem on Inheritance"

Comment: @Yuushi: Oh, I see. Maybe you're right, in which case, I agree.

Comment: @Tom: Except for `std::streambuf` -- that one you're supposed to inherit.

Comment: So if you don't inherit form a string class, do you just make one of your own? Is that even possible?

Comment: Aside from using a string class, am I actually doing the inheritance part correctly? The code works fine like this, but just because it works doesn't mean it's being done correctly

Comment: It seems that all of your questions on SO spend a good amount of time explaining where your questions come from and assuring us that they're not assignments, which leads me to believe that these are all your assignments.  SO is not your homework fairy.  Please stop.

Comment: Um, it's not homework. I go out of my way to let people know that because I know most forums wont help with homework, and I don't want anyone thinking otherwise. I literally look up unanswered questions on-line, and when I can't understand them, I go to places like these for help. Because of this post, I gave up on the apparently stupid idea of inheriting from a stl class, but did use some of the suggestions to learn about inheritance, and I now have a far better understanding of it, and the book I have now makes a lot more sense. Regardless of what you may think, I'm here to learn, not cheat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside a generally good advice to *not* inherit from `std` containers, preferring *composition* instead, you are still not doing it right: the method `howLong` (and the rest of the methods that they expect you to define) are supposed to operate on the string itself, not on a string passed in:

```
int howLong(); // no args

int strMetric::howLong() {
    // Using "this" below is optional
    return this->size(); // remember, this *is* a string
}
```

The rest of the methods will do the same thing - they will *not* take a string argument, and use `this` instead.

> How in the world can you do the other methods using this-> instead of loading in a string argument?

The remaining methods are not different - simply take the string inside your own object. I am nearly certain that learning how to do this is the point of the exercise. For example, to add vowel counter, you do something like this:

```
int vowelCnt(); // again, no args

int strMetric:: vowelCnt() {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != this->size() ; i++) {
        char ch = (*this)[i]; // Yes, this works
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'u' || ch == ...) {
            res++;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: So in my header I initialize it without any overloads, and then overload it with a string in my cpp file, and then use this to cal on the string from the string class?

Comment: @MichellePeoples: No, no overloads. You just don't take any arguments.  I'm not sure why das did the example this way and left the argument in.  Probably just a typo.

Comment: A better question would be, how in the world can you do the other methods using this-> instead of loading in a string argument? I can do them all loading in either `chars *s` or `string s`, but I don't think I've ever seen it done with a `this->` pointer

Comment: @MichellePeoples Take a look at the update to see how it can be done. I think you were missing the `(*this)[i]` part.

Comment: Ok, so I have this for counting the string in ASCII `int charSum(string x, int i)
{
  if(x.size() == i)
    return (0 + x[i]);
  else
    return charSum(x, i + 1) + x[i];
}` and I am trying to do it the way your saying, and going with this: `int strMetric::sumChars()
{
 int x = 0;
  if(this->size() == x)
   return (0 + (*this)[x]);
  else
    return this->x + 1 + (*this)[x];
}` But it does not return the current count for the characters being scanned, any idea why?

Comment: @MichellePeoples The reason it always returns the same number of characters is that the string is always the same. You can do it recursively, but that's much worse than doing it iteratively with a loop: just replace the entire `if` statement with unconditional `res += (*this)[i];`

Comment: Yeah, I threw in a for loop, added what you said inside and returned the res and it finally works. Sheesh, and I thought the inheritance stuff was a pain. I wasn't worried about the methods since I can do those pretty easy, and it turns out, those are the hard parts.

Comment: It took a bit of rethinking how I see things, but after I started treating this-> as though it was just string s;, it all started making more sense, and I have all the methods working now according to how you said to do it, so thank you! Now to go practice on real inheritance...